# open a web page through java that need Authentication

Tags: java, html, authentication, web

I am trying to open a web page that need user name and password through JAVA:
[page I am trying to acces](https://reports.tradenetworks.com/ReportServer_DISTRIBUTORRS?%2FDealing&rs:Command=ListChildren)

this is my code copied referenced [from this site](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-connect-to-a-url-using-basic-authentication.html) :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String webPage = "https://reports.tradenetworks.com/ReportServer_DISTRIBUTORRS?%2fDealing&rs:Command=ListChildren";
        String name = "Tradenetworks\\USER";
        String password = "PASS";
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string:" + authStringEnc);

        URL url = new URL(webPage);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        int numCharsRead;
        char[] charArray = new char[1024];
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
            sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
        }
        String result = sb.toString();

        System.out.println("*** BEGIN ***");
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("*** END ***");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but I get this error from eclipse:

```
java.io.IOException: Authentication failure
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at ConnectToUrlUsingBasicAuthentication.main(ConnectToUrlUsingBasicAuthentication.java:27)
```

Comment: No, you get that error from the site's webserver, not from Eclipse. Stop shooting the messenger. So now you have to debug your problem, and I would start by outputting that base64 encoding string to see what is actually in there - probably it is not correct. That tends to happen when you just copy/paste code from some random site. You did try to open the url in a browser, right? It would be a shame if the username/password is actually just wrong.

Comment: hey the username and password are correct I rechecked that how can i now if base64 is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the `username` String having slashes (`\\`). Those chars look like this when URL encoded: `%5C%5C`. So, you should try `String name = "Tradenetworks%5C%5CUSER";`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue! I managed to get the code working by using custom authenticator:

```
try {
    // Sets the authenticator that will be used by the networking code
    // when a proxy or an HTTP server asks for authentication.
    Authenticator.setDefault(new CustomAuthenticator());

    URL url = new URL(webPage);

    // read text returned by server
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

And here is the implementation of customAuthendicator.

```
public static class CustomAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    // Called when password authorization is needed
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        String username = "ImtLis";
        String password = "ImtLis2017";
        // Return the information (a data holder that is used by
        // Authenticator)
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }

}
```

Hope this helps. Information source: [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/authenticator/access-password-protected-url-with-authenticator/).